# Difficult Grouping Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, pivot

I am having trouble writing a query to get the results I want.  I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[inputs](
    [iid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [tag_id] [int] NULL,
    [date_time] [datetime] NULL,
    [input_raw] [float] NULL,
    [input_calibrated] [float] NULL,
    [input_type] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [virtual_record] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [status_change] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [prev_stat_chg] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [prev_status_change] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [unix_timestamp] [float] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_inputs] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [iid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,   ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]`
)
```

I am writing a query to get the data in a format which can be used with a timeline graph that I have.  Needing the data "Grouped By" "unix_timestamp" with "n" number of tag_id's "input_raw".

For example:

```
SELECT TOP 20 inputs.unix_timestamp, inputs.input_raw, inputs.tag_id 
FROM [200030].[dbo].inputs
WHERE inputs.tag_id = 92149 or inputs.tag_id = 92164
ORDER BY unix_timestamp DESC
```

Gives me the results:

```
unix_timestamp  input_raw   tag_id
1357788990  313         92149
1357788990  210         92164
1357788690  313         92149
1357788690  210         92164
1357788390  313         92149
1357788390  210         92164
1357788090  313         92149
1357788090  210         92164
1357787790  313         92149
1357787790  210         92164
1357787490  313         92149
1357787490  210         92164
1357787190  313         92149
1357787190  210         92164
1357786890  313         92149
1357786890  210         92164
1357786590  313         92149
1357786590  210         92164
1357786290  313         92149
1357786290  210         92164
```

I need a result that looks like:

```
unix_timestamp     tag(92149)     tag(92164)
1357788990         313            210
1357788690         313            210
|
|
Vetc...
```

Also needing a string "undefined" or a 'NULL' if there is any missing data from one tag if there is any other data for the other tags on a timestamp.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pivot of the data. You did not specify what RDBMS you are using but you can use the following in all databases:

```
SELECT unix_timestamp,
  max(case when inputs.tag_id = 92149 then input_raw else null end) tag_92149,
  max(case when inputs.tag_id = 92164 then input_raw else null end) tag_92164
FROM [200030].[dbo].inputs
GROUP BY unix_timestamp
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f7dcc/1)

If you are using a database with a `PIVOT` function (SQL Server/Oracle) then you can use:

```
select *
from
(
  select unix_timestamp,
    input_raw,
    tag_id 
  from [200030].[dbo].inputs
) src
pivot
(
  max(input_raw)
  for tag_id in ([92149], [92164])
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f7dcc/4)

The result of both is:

```
| UNIX_TIMESTAMP | 92149 | 92164 |
----------------------------------
|     1357786290 |   313 |   210 |
|     1357786590 |   313 |   210 |
|     1357786890 |   313 |   210 |
|     1357787190 |   313 |   210 |
|     1357787490 |   313 |   210 |
|     1357787790 |   313 |   210 |
|     1357788090 |   313 |   210 |
|     1357788390 |   313 |   210 |
|     1357788690 |   313 |   210 |
|     1357788990 |   313 |   210 |
```

Comment: Perfect everybody gave correct answers but this is the closest to what I needed.  I added "WHERE tag_id = 92149 or tag_id = 92164" so i wouldn't get NULL results from the thousands of other tags that are in the DB.  A second part is that I have a tag table to which the tag_id is tied to.  One field is "inverted" which is a flag "flip" the data for graphing.  Do you recommend a trigger to do the math or is there a JOIN or something I could use to include the inverted field for each tag_id.  The tag_id is the PK->FK between the two tables.

Comment: @KevinKent happy to help. What Database are you using?

Comment: mssql is what we are using if that's what you are asking.

Comment: @KevinKent I am not fully understanding the second part of your comment. It sounds like you can join but without more details it would be difficult.

Comment: table tag includes more detailed data about each tag.  the inputs table is just for historical data i.e. graphs/reports.  tag_id from inputs is tied to tags.tag_id.  within tags is a field called "inverted".  This is a flag which indicated if the data coming into the inputs table needs to be "flipped" i.e. abs(1-input_raw).  I would like to do this sql side as opposed to php side.  If my comment is still confusing I apologize.

Comment: @KevinKent Sounds like you might have to post a new question that outlines what you are trying to do, with some sample data for each table and then the desired result.  I think it will be too difficult to figure out from comments. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  unix_timestamp,
        MAX(CASE WHEN tag = 92149 THEN input_raw ELSE NULL END) [tag92149],
        MAX(CASE WHEN tag = 92164 THEN input_raw ELSE NULL END) [tag92164]
FROM    tableName
GROUP BY unix_timestamp
```

OR

```
SELECT unix_timestamp, [92149] As tag92149, [92164] as tag92164
FROM
    (
      SELECT    unix_timestamp, 
                tag,
                input_raw
      FROM      tableName
    ) a
    PIVOT
    (
      MAX(input_raw)
      for tag in ([92149], [92164])
    ) b
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a pivoting query.  You can do this in any database using:

```
select unix_timestamp, 
       max(case when tag = 92149 then input_raw end) as tag_92349,
       max(case when tag = 92164 then input_raw end) as tag_92164
from (SELECT TOP 20 inputs.unix_timestamp, inputs.input_raw, inputs.tag_id 
     FROM [200030].[dbo].inputs
     WHERE inputs.tag_id = 92149 or inputs.tag_id = 92164
    ) t
group by unix_timestamp
ORDER BY unix_timestamp DESC
```